# How to move position of graph?

Tags: d3.js

I am saving the initial positions for the x and y coordinates of some circles inside 2 different arrays : xNodeValues and yNodeValues. I am moving the d3 circles around and when I press the update button, I want to put the circles back to their original position. I am using this method:

```
        const xnodes=this.xNodeValues;
        const ynodes=this.yNodeValues;

        this.svg=d3.selectAll('circle')
        .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("cx", function(d:any, i: number) {
            console.log("Initial X position is (from update method)"+xnodes[i]);
            return(xnodes[i])
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d:any, i: number) {
            console.log("Initial Y position is (from update method)"+ynodes[i]);
            return(ynodes[i])})

    }
```

But somehow the circles don't go back to their original position. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
const xnodes=this.xNodeValues;
const ynodes=this.yNodeValues;
```

You are copying the value reference, not the value it self, so after you move the circle, the "xnodes" and "ynodes" values are also going to be changed.

Try doing one of theese:

```
// Old way to copy array values
const xnodes= this.xNodeValues.slice();
const ynodes= this.yNodeValues.slice();

// ES6 way to copy array values (preferable if supported)
const xnodes= [...this.xNodeValues];
const ynodes= [...this.yNodeValues];
```

Doing it like this, you preserve the original values at "xnodes" and "ynodes" even after moving the circle.

Comment: I tried it like this, but the circles don't move to their original position. The values of the x and y arrays are the same though

Answer (score 0):

By moving around I assume you're dragging your nodes.
You need to define a drag variable with d3 behaviour drag and add dragstarted, dragged and dragended functionality to the drag variable's .on property.

function dragstarted's definition is simple one-liner.

```
function dragstarted(d) {
    d3.event.whatervertransition or propagation
    d3.select(this).classed("drags", true);
}
```

For function dragged() update the node's x & y to the x & y of the canvas

```
function dragged(d) {
    var dragval= d3.mouse(this.parentNode);
    d.x = dragval[0];
    d.y = dragval[1];

    d3.select(this)
       .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")" });
}
```

Now in function dragended is where you'd want to re-set your node's x & y position

```
 function dragended(d) {
    d3.select(this).classed("drags", false);

    if (condition to reset) {
        var x = initialValX
        var y = initialValY
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I have already the dragged functionality working. I need to restart the position of the circles to the original one(after dragging them)

Comment: You will have to provide us with more view of your code then.